# Counting with placeholders

Tags: python

How to manage that placeholder will start counting from 1. For example, if the input is 3, how can I display "enter the number 1", "enter the number 2" and "enter the number3"

```
numbers = int(input("how many numbers do you want? "))
    for i in range(numbers):
        x = int(input("enter the number " + "%d" % ()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not old enough to comment, so have to put this as an answer..

As per your code, you will be ended with 'x' having only the last number, to avoid this, you can probably define x as a list and keep appending to it so that you also capture the previous entries.

```
numbers = int(input("how many numbers do you want? "))
x = []
for i in range(numbers):
    x.append(int(input("enter the number " + str(i+1))))
```

Comment: Or even better you can use dictionary to know which entry had what value.
b = {}
for i in range(1, numbers+1):
 b[i] = int(input("enter the number " + str(i)))

Answer (score 2):

For this simple case, forego the placeholder and just append the string

```
numbers = int(input("how many numbers do you want? "))
for i in range(numbers):
    x = int(input("enter the number " + str(i+1)))
```

Otherwise, you can look at using [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure why this is something you would like but if you need more help, just ask!

```
numbers = int(input("how many numbers do you want? "))
for i in range(1, numbers+1):
    cur = input(f"enter the number {i}: ")
    x = int(cur)
    # Do something with x?
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using fstrings as below:

```
numbers = int(input("how many numbers do you want? "))
for i in range(numbers):
    x = int(input(f"enter the number {i+1}"))
```

(you should use `i+1` if you want to start from 1)